# Can Runtime.getRuntime().exec a classpath resource?

Tags: java, spring, exec

Here is my code

```
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:run.sh");
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

but when I do

```
Runtime.getRunTime().exec(path)
```

it throw a FileNotFoundException

```
class path resource [run.sh] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it 
  does not reside in the file system: 
  jar:file:/root/backend-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/run.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your OS doesn't know how to run application from archives.